# Microsoft Graph List Sign Ins 30 Day Limit

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm attempting to use the Microsoft Graph API to query the sign in history of an app (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/signin-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). It only returns at most the last 30 days worth of history. Is this by design or am I missing a parameter?

My filter string is
`"(appId eq '_REDACTED_GUID_') and (createdDateTime ge 2020-11-01)"`

I do not receive results prior to 30 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD stores sign-in data for the last 30 days. It is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/reference-reports-data-retention#how-long-does-azure-ad-store-the-data) depending on the plans.